# Syntax highlighting by pattern

Tags: vim

I've been using a syntax highlight for some time to match space characters that come after leading tabs.

```
 autocmd Syntax * highlight LeadingSpaces guibg=#afd7af ctermbg=Black
 autocmd Syntax * syntax match LeadingSpaces /^\t\+\zs \+/
```

Problem is, it doesn't always work. For example, inside block comments the highlight doesn't take effect:

```
 test  // the extra space before "test" gets highlighted
/**
 * test  // here the extra spaces aren't highlighted
 */
```

If anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. Otherwise I'll have to go back to regular matching, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem (but display trailing spaces at the end of the line). To solve it, instead of using syntax, which interferes with the actual syntax you can just highlight a regular expression using `matchadd`.

This look like this (reusing your LeadingSpaces )

```
autocmd BufNew * call matchadd ('LeadingSpaces', '^\t\+\zs \+')
```

Comment: I ended up with a similar solution, so I'm accepting this. Thanks